# Joomla textarea replaces newlines with __ (2 underscores)

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, textarea, fieldset

Good day to you all,

I am not exactly a Joomla Expert. Afters hours of searching the net for an answer, i decided to try it here.

I am writing a simple Joomla component. In the view part I have a view called 'information'. I want in the backend that the administrator can add some text.

This is how the default.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Informationform">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[Informationform]]>
        </message>
    </layout>

    <fields name="request">
        <fieldset name="request" label="Contactform Properties">
            <field name="templatename" type="text" label="E-mail-templatename"></field>
            <field name="extracss" type="textarea" rows="8" cols="40" filter="raw" label="Extra CSS"></field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</metadata>
```

In the backend I can add the contact form as a menutitem. On the rightside I can edit my extra fields.
After I input some lines of text in the textarea and saved the menu-item. All newline-characters are replaced by __ (2 underscores).

Original text:

```
This is an example 
text.
As you can see there 
are multiple lines.
```

After saving the text:

```
This is an example__text.__As you can see there__are multiple lines.
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: How are you making the line breaks?

Comment: Thats simple. Behind my keyboard I hit the enter-key, inside the text area.

Comment: I suspect it is doing \r\n and that is getting stripped out by the input filters.  How about using <br/> instead?